# How to write a (public String makeFields()) method in class BuildClass which generates a String?

Tags: java

I made this class called `BuildClass` with a method makeFields()`. I want the methods to generate a`String` corresponding to the field
variable declarations at the start of the corresponding class file .

The methods strings should show what a java program in eclipse shows for example toString method.

This is what I have done. But instead of just for class BuildName, I want it to be able to show any class. The method should be able to get the class name and use it. How do I get the class name and use it in the method?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

   public class BuildClass {

   private String className;
   private ArrayList<Var> fields;

   public String makeFields() {
        return "BuildClass [className=" + className + ", fields=" + fields + "]";
      }
   }
```

Comment: You declared `String` as return type but the method returns `0` which is `int`. Instead of `return 0;` use something like `return null;` or `return "0";`.

Comment: *It keeps giving me errors*: Exactly what errors do you get? I see you have a `}` too much.